# Karatsuba does not return correct result because of middle-term

Tags: java, multiplication, karatsuba

Here is my code:

```
public static double kMultiply( double x, double y, double n )
{
    if( n == 1 )
    {
        cost += 1;
        return x*y;
    }
    else
    {
        double m,a,b,c,d,ac,bd,g;

        m = Math.floor(n/2);

        a = Math.floor(x / Math.pow(2,m));
        b = x % Math.pow(2,m);
        c = Math.floor(y / Math.pow(2,m));
        d = y % Math.pow(2,m);

        ac = kMultiply(a,c,m);
        bd = kMultiply(b,d,m);
        g  = kMultiply(a-b, c-d, m);

        cost += 6*m;
        return Math.pow(2,2*m)*ac + Math.pow(2,m)*(ac + bd - g) + bd;

    }
}
```

x and y are the factors and n is the size of the greater number and is described as the number bits required to write that number in binary representation.
For some values of x and y, this algorithm does not return correct value of x*y, because I can't get the correct g. For example, for

```
kMultiply(4, 11, 4)
```

the method returns 52 instead of 44, because it assigns -3 to g, instead of -1.

Any idea how I can fix this? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you try to debug it in your IDE, or with a pencil and paper?

Comment: Yes, I did both, for hours.